# Equal space for td in html table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an html table like below and I want to make the `td` spaces equal. The first `name Jean Claud Anita Goth` is quite long and pushes the `grade 5` away. The long names should be wrapped.

**How it looks like now**

```
 Name              Class
 Frew Amamde          5        
    Jean Claud Anita Goth       5
```

**What I want**

```
 Name              Class
 Frew Amamde          5        
 Jean Claud Anita     5
 Goth
```

**HTML**

```html
<table class="table" id="tables">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Class</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>Jean Claud Anita Goth</td>
    <td>grade 5</td>

    <td>Frew Amamde</td>
    <td>grade 5</td>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Include your CSS please

Comment: Is your example supposed to be missing the `<tr>` between the entries?

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

That's due to errors in the HTML code: The empty `th` element (to be erased) and the missing `tr` tags for the rows below the header (to be added):

```css
th {
text-align: left;
}
td, th {
padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table" id="tables">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Class</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jean Claud Anita Goth</td>
      <td>grade 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Frew Amamde</td>
      <td>grade 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```